# Groupby as columns with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a dataframe similar to

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.np.random.randint(1, 10, (20, 2)),
    index=["a", "b", "c", "d"] * 5,
    columns=["foo", "bar"],
)
```

looking something like this

[image: df]

I'm trying to get it into the following multi-index form: two columns for each of the 4 axis labels each with a "foo" and "bar" sub-column:

[image: df-target]

I've tried fiddling around with `df.groupby(df.index)` but then I can't figure out how to turn the groups into columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for `MultiIndex` in index with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and change order of `Multiindex` in columns by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)
         .unstack(0)
         .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=[0,1], ascending=[True, False]))
print (df1)
    a       b       c       d    
  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
0   6   8   1   6   8   4   6   1
1   2   6   4   5   3   1   5   4
2   2   5   2   9   5   4   8   9
3   5   2   6   6   7   3   2   9
4   4   8   9   6   4   2   1   5
```